# GoogleApiClient stops to work properly after GPS turned on/off

Tags: android, gps, google-api-client, android-location, android-googleapiclient

I'm trying to implement abstract Activity, whose inheritants would be able to get Location data. I'm strictly following **[this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)**, that seems pretty straightforward.

But after all I have a few problems. Google API should pass location data even if GPS is off, getting this from network data or even passive data from other apps. But in my case it works only with GPS enabled.

Another question is what happens when I turn GPS off/on. In my case after that I can't het any data at all.

Here's the class that makes everything done.

```
public abstract class LocationProviderActivity extends BaseDrawerActivity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


    private final String TAG = "LOCATION";
    GoogleApiClient client;
    protected Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (client == null) {
            client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        client.connect();
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        client.disconnect();
        Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //TODO
            return;
        }
        location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(client);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
}
```

Comment: post your code to help debugging

Comment: Added the code for my abstract Activity.